# want to delete ith matching pattern from file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

i want to delete the static entry from dhcpd.cong file by using shell command. Currently I am using sed for the hostname. But there are multiple static entries for same hostname. here is the portion from sample dhcpd.conf file:

```
host my-system4 {
  hardware ethernet 11:22:33:44:55:66;
  fixed-address 192.168.17.54;
}

host my-system4 {
  hardware ethernet 22:33:44:55:66:77;
  fixed-address 192.168.17.34;
}
```

Here i used:

```
sed -i '/host my-system4/,/^\}/d' xyz.txt
```

But this command is deleting all the host my-system4 entries from file. How can I delete the specific entry by doing grep on fixed-address. Also the number of lines under host my-system4 may also vary. I nee shell command which do grep on fixed-address and delete only that specific host entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

```
sed -e :a -e '/host my-system4/,/}/ { /}/!{ $!{N;ba};};/pattern/d;}' filename
```

to delete the *entry* containing the specified *pattern*.

For example,

```
sed -e :a -e '/host my-system4/,/}/ { /}/!{ $!{N;ba};};/192\.168\.17\.34/d;}' filename
```

would delete the entry containing the fixed address `192.168.17.34`.  Note that `.` has been escaped so as to match a literal `.`.

---

If the *entries* in the file are guaranteed to be separated by a blank line, you could simplify it by saying:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/pattern/d' filename
```

where the *pattern* in the command above denotes the *entry* to be deleted.

---

Add the `-i` option for in-place editing:

```
sed -i -e :a -e '/host my-system4/,/}/ { /}/!{ $!{N;ba};};/192\.168\.17\.34/d;}' filename
```

or

```
sed -i -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/pattern/d' filename
```

Comment: Thanks devnull. This works for me. But if i want to use -i option to make this change in file itself, how should I use it?

Comment: got it!!! it will be like: sed -i ':a;/host my-system4/,/}/ { /}/!{ $!{N;ba};};/192\.168\.17\.34/d;}' tmp.txt

Answer (score 1):

One solution using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim).

```
vim -u NONE -N \
    -c 'set backup | g/\vfixed-address\s+192\.168\.17\.34/ normal dap' \
    -c 'x' infile
```

It creates a backup of the file appending `~` to the name. Remove `set backup` and the pipe if you want to risk yourself to lose data. It uses a global replacement to search the line `fixed-address 192.168.17.34` and selects the whole paragraph to delete it. The last `x` command saves the modified file.